# OTP SMS Verification Code without the use of MVC and asp identity,core

Tags: c#

How do i send a One-Time-Password verification to phone  just normal web form and calling methods and classes not using asp identity etc.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: _Security is hard_.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven, authentication system.